# python code changes url page number when i scrape 10 rows from table but not 100

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, url, beautifulsoup

url with 100 lines in row is [Link-1](https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2C%20London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=100&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET%20DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow%20City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET=London%20Road&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=%20%20&PT=1&&PT=1#results).

Url with 10 lines in row is the same with display count=10, [Link-2](https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2C%20London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&PAGE=0&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET%20DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow%20City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET=London%20Road&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=%20%20&PT=1&&PT=1#results).

my code is changing page when i scrape using display count = 10, albeit it begins scraping at  page 11. however when i try to use the same code using the 100 display count it stops at 100. this is despite the below link where i have simply change the page to =1 presenting lines 101-200 in my browser. any idea why my code can't scrape. full code is below. thanks in advance.
[Liink-3](https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2C%20London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&PAGE=1&DISPLAY_COUNT=100&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET%20DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=London%20Road%2C%20GLASGOW%2C%20Glasgow%20City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow%20City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET=London%20Road&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=%20%20&PT=1&&PT=1#results).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv


outputfilename = 'ggw_LondonRoad10.csv'

inputfilename = 'ggw100_streets.txt'
#inputfilename = 'Edinburgh.txt'

outputfile = open(outputfilename, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(outputfile)

writer.writerow(['URL', 'Local Council','Town','Locality','Street','Reference', 'Description', 'Address', 'Proprietor','Tenant','Occupier','Current Value','Pre-Revaluation 2010','Proposed Value 2017'])


base_url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

session = requests.session()

#read input file
inputfile = open(inputfilename,'rb')  
streets = inputfile.readlines()

for a_street in streets :

#ed_street=a_street.strip('\r\n')
ggw100_streets=a_street.strip('\r\n')

page_num = 0

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2C'+ggw100_streets+'%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&PAGE='+str(page_num)+'&DISPLAY_COUNT=100&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM='+ggw100_streets+'%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow+City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET='+ggw100_streets+'&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=++&&PT=1#results'

response = session.get(url)

if 'postcode incorrectly' in response.content:

    print 'Street unknown:', ggw100_streets

else:
    empty_rslt= False
    while not empty_rslt :
        #url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2CLondon+Road%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&PAGE='+str(page_num)+'&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=London+Road%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow+City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET=London+Road&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=++&&PT=1#results'
        url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search/?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=glasgow%2C'+ggw100_streets+'%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&PAGE='+str(page_num)+'&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CPD&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&ORIGINAL_SEARCH_TERM=glasgow&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM='+ggw100_streets+'%2C+GLASGOW%2C+Glasgow+City&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Glasgow+City&DD_TOWN=GLASGOW&DD_STREET='+ggw100_streets+'&DEBUG_LEVEL=0&SEARCH_METHOD=++&&PT=1#results'
        response = session.get(url)
        html = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

        prop_link = html.find_all("a", class_="pagelink button small")
        if len(prop_link) != 0:
            for link in prop_link:

                prop_url = base_url+(link["href"])
            #print prop_url

                response = session.get(prop_url)
                prop = soup(response.content,"lxml")


                LeftBlockData = prop.find_all("div", class_="columns small-7 medium-8 cell")
                Reference = LeftBlockData[0].get_text().strip()
                print (Reference)

                writer.writerow([prop_url, Reference])

            page_num+=1
        else:
            empty_rslt= True
```

Comment: What problem you are facing, I mean can you explain what exactly you are not able to scrape.

Comment: You have indentation errors, by the way. Correct those first.